# Get part of url and paste it at the end of same url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

i would like to know if there is a way to rewrite an url by cutting a piece and then pasting it again at the end of the new url.
this is how the url should look like:

?route=module/mega_filter/results&mfp=110-soort,port,rose

but it displays as:

/mfp/110-soort,port,rose?route=module/mega_filter/results

so this piece in fornt of the ?

/mfp/110-soort,port,rose

needs to be cut and then pasted behind the rest....now the piece that needs to be at the end can be different because it is a filter and many options are possible.

thanks

Comment: What does your Rewrite definition look like? Are you using Apache httpd `[QSA]`?

Answer (score 0):

If the original URL is guaranteed to always be the same initial structure (i.e. `<some characters>?<other characters>`) and you're always looking to take the first set and put them after the last set, you could easily remove the leading `/`, split this string on `?`, and reorder the values:

```
$original_url = '/mfp/110-soort,port,rose?route=module/mega_filter/results';
$strip_leading_slash = substr($original_url, 1, strlen($original_url));
$split = explode('?', $strip_leading_slash);
$final_url = '?' . $split[1] . '&' . $split[0];
```

Of course, this is a very literal way to solve this problem. If the string structure will differ, you should look into Regular Expressions and [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).